# Use WebMatrix to work on non WebMatrix site

Tags: webmatrix

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Microsoft's WebMatrix to work on a site that was not originally created using WebMatrix.

The site I want to work on is nothing fancy. Just basic html, css, php, and mySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. If you have installed WebMatrix, you have a new option when right-clicking on any folder: Open As Web Site with WebMatrix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know if there is a way to do this over an FTP connection? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. You can "Download Published Site" by clicking the small down-arrow beneath the Publish button in WebMatrix. You must first enter the FTP login credentials first though.

Answer (score 1):

No. WebMatrix version 1 (7.1.1073.1) does not let you download a published site with FTP unless it was uploaded with Web Deploy and the hosting provider is suitably Microsoft compatible:

```
Unable to download site
The site cannot be downloaded using FTP.
You can download only a site that was published using Web Deploy.
```

I can't imagine that Microsoft would regard this as a bug, more as a marketing opportunity!